# How migrate jqpl query to Criteria API

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria-api

Please have this query in jpql i want migrate to criteria. How do I you that?

The Query:

```
SELECT c FROM Cartera c,Cliente cli WHERE c.aseId = :aseId and cli.aseId=c.aseId
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Cartera> query = cb.createQuery(Cartera.class);
Root<Cartera> cartera = query.from(Cartera.class);
Root<Cliente> cliente = query.from(Cliente.class);
query.select(cartera);
query.where(cb.equal(cartera.get(Cartera_.aseId), theAseId),
            cb.equal(cliente.get(Cliente_.aseId), theAseId));
```

should do the trick. Not tested, though.

Answer (score 0):

After JB Nizet's answer you will also have to have

```
TypedQuery<Cartera> tq = em.createQuery(query);
tq.setFirstResult( offset );  // how many records to skip 
tq.setMaxResults( pageSize);  // don't want to fetch a million records
List<Cartera> list = tq.getResultList();
```